# Jquery Get request doesn't echo anything from php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my function in javascript.

```
function saveScore() {
        $.get('save-score.php', function (output){
        alert(output);  
        });  

    };
```

Then the php file in the same directory (save-score.php):

```
<?php
    
    echo "hello";

?>
```

Nothing gets alerted for some reason. I've used jquery get request before so I don't know why this doesn't work...

Comment: Is there no console errors? Are you sure the function `saveScore()` is being called ?

Comment: theres a console error, something about same origin policy...
the function is defo being called though.

Comment: I've just tried your code and it's perfectly working! Are you using a Web server ?

Comment: no its on localhost...

Comment: Yes I understand that, but my question is, is your `save-score.php` file is being executed using a web server? Means is the file located under `www` folder of wamp and apache server is up ? (for example)

Comment: i realised my mistake. i was loading the file directly (file explorer) but not using localhost/file

Comment: _something about same origin policy_ Thats a clue :) Read it, research it, and why not show it all to us as well

Comment: i figured it out as above. your comment makes coding sound like a puzzle game.

Comment: Well thats exectly what DEBUGGING is :)